# Registry Key Controlling Start Button in Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-registry, start-menu

This is related to [How to hide “Start” button in Windows 8.1?](https://superuser.com/questions/612754/how-to-hide-start-button-in-windows-8-1).

I've got the useless, castrated, Microsoft provided start menu next to a 3rd party start menu. I'd like to remove Microsoft's useless, castrated start button. I want to remove it though the registry, without using yet another app store app.

I tried searching the registry, but the soft keyboard does not provide <kbd>F3</kbd>. So I can't quickly search the registry. I also tried removing it via a *Local Security Policy*, but it appears Microsoft has removed the item (or its only available on domain computers).

In essence, I need to know the keys shown under *Centralized Configuration* in Microsoft's technet article [Exploring Windows 8.1 Start Screen and Start Button Options and Configurations](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askpfeplat/archive/2013/10/17/exploring-windows-8-1-start-screen-and-start-button-options-and-configurations.aspx).

And I don't have the ***RollBackToWindows8Build9200*** key discussed in [Disable Windows 8.1 Start Button](http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/157824-Disable-Windows-8-1-Start-Button) (someone suggested it was a prank). I tired to add it but it did not help.

What is the registry key Microsoft uses to control the presence of their start button? What key is tools like [7+ Taskbar Tweaker](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker) writing to?

Comment: BTW, you can [enable the full keyboard](http://winaero.com/blog/enable-the-full-keyboard-standard-keyboard-layout-in-the-touch-keyboard-of-windows-8-1/) for the touch keyboard, if you want F3 there. Or you can use the older accessibility On-Screen Keyboard.

Comment: Looks like there simply isn't a registry key. What gives you the impression that the tweaker is using one? It could be directly interfering with how the taskbar is drawn. Consider updating or changing your third-party start menu to one that supports 8.1 (and therefore hiding the built-in button).

Comment: If you consider the registry option may well be impossible (it'll only work if MS actually put that option in), this question essentially becomes a duplicate of [this other one](http://superuser.com/questions/612754/how-to-hide-start-button-in-windows-8-1).

Comment: It looks like 7+ Taskbar Tweaker does not do anything to the registry. `The only registry keys the tweaker modifies are its own settings. There are no registry keys for the options it provides. The tweaker does that by injecting a DLL to explorer, hooking/subclassing/some other methods of the dark side.` That's what is says on the website. The program modifies/adds/replaces DLLs to do what you want to do. As @Bob said, I don't think there is a registry tweak to remove the start button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RPEnabled "0" in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer no longer works?
 Dam you Microsoft!